# awk simple calculator-function behaving strangely in a working dir containing a one-letter dir

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I defined the following awk function in my .bashrc:

```
? () { awk "BEGIN{ pi=3.14159265359; printf \"%5.5f\n\", $* }" ; }
```

When I execute this function in a directory containing a one-letter directory, this will give me an error.

```
> ls
B
> ? "1+2"
B: command not found # B refers to the one-letter dir?
```

The function works fine if executed in some other directory that doesn't contain any one-letter directories.

I also did some further test. When I executed this function in a directory containing a one-letter file, this also gives me error:

```
> ? "1+2"
-bash: ./B: Permission denied # B now refers to a file
```

Could anyone tell me what's going wrong here?

Comment: The shell expands `?` to single letter filenames. If there is no single character filename in the current folder the `?` won't get expanded and stays a literal `?`. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got it wrong. The `?` has a special meaning which the shell interprets as, meaning to match a single character. That's why the expansion results in a single character filename, i.e. glob expansion happens before the shell looks up functions or commands. Had there been such files with single character names, it would have expanded to a literal string `?`

From `man bash`

> `Pathname Expansion`
>
> After  word  splitting,  unless  the `-f` option has been set, bash scans
>   each word for the characters `*`, `?`, and `[`.  If one of  these  characters
>   appears,  then  the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern
>
> The special pattern characters have the following meanings:
>
> `?`      Matches any single character.

Would recommend a way to use the `awk` import shell variables option `-v` to import args than use double-quotes to avoid having to take care of special cases. Also consider using a better function name than any of the shell meta-characters

```
awkf () { awk -v argv="$*" 'BEGIN{ pi=3.14159265359; printf "%5.5f\n", argv }' ; }
```

But for a use-case for a simple calculator like using the string `1+2` inside the expression, you could use double-quotes properly

```
awkf () { awk "BEGIN{ pi=3.14159265359; printf \"%5.5f\n\", "$*" }" ; }
```

Comment: So the important point is that glob expansion happens before the shell looks up functions or commands.